# Wordnet synsets using perl

Tags: perl, wordnet

I installed [Wordnet::Similarity](http://search.cpan.org/~tpederse/WordNet-Similarity-2.05/lib/WordNet/Similarity.pm) and [Wordnet::QueryData](http://search.cpan.org/dist/WordNet-QueryData/QueryData.pm) as an easy way to calculate information content score and probability that comes with these modules. But I'm stuck at this basic problem: given a word, print n words similar to it - which should not be difficult that iterating through the synsets and doing `join`.

using the `wn` command and piping it with a whole lot of `tr`, `sort | uniq` I can get all the words:

```
 wn cat -synsn | grep -v Sense | tr '=' ' ' | tr '>' ' ' | tr '\t' ' ' | tr ',' '\n' | sort | uniq
```

**OUTPUT**

```
8 senses of cat                                                         
adult female
adult male
African tea
Arabian tea
big cat
bozo
cat
cat
CAT
Caterpillar
cat-o'-nine-tails
 computed axial tomography
computed tomography
computerized axial tomography
computerized tomography
CT
excitant
felid
      feline
      gossip
gossiper
gossipmonger
guy
hombre
kat
khat
      man
newsmonger
qat
quat
rumormonger
rumourmonger
      stimulant
stimulant drug
Synonyms/Hypernyms (Ordered by Estimated Frequency) of noun cat
      tracked vehicle
true cat
      whip
      woman
X-radiation
      X-raying
```

but its kinda nasty,and needs further clean up.

What my script looks like is below, and what I want to get is all the words in cat#n1...8.

**SCRIPT**

```
use WordNet::QueryData;

my $wn = WordNet::QueryData->new( noload => 1);

print "Senses: ", join(", ", $wn->querySense("cat#n")), "\n";
print "Synset: ", join(", ", $wn->querySense("cat", "syns")), "\n";
print "Hyponyms: ", join(", ", $wn->querySense("cat#n#1", "hypo")), "\n";
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Senses: cat#n#1, cat#n#2, cat#n#3, cat#n#4, cat#n#5, cat#n#6, cat#n#7, cat#n#8
Synset: cat#n, cat#v
Hyponyms: domestic_cat#n#1, wildcat#n#3
```

---

**SCRIPT**

```
use WordNet::QueryData;
my $wn = WordNet::QueryData->new;

foreach $word (qw/cat#n/) {

    @senses = $wn->querySense($word);

    foreach $wps (@senses) {
            @gloss = $wn -> querySense($wps, "syns");
            print "$wps : @gloss\n";
    }

}
```

OUTPUT:

```
cat#n#1 : cat#n#1 true_cat#n#1
cat#n#2 : guy#n#1 cat#n#2 hombre#n#1 bozo#n#2
cat#n#3 : cat#n#3
cat#n#4 : kat#n#1 khat#n#1 qat#n#1 quat#n#1 cat#n#4 Arabian_tea#n#1 African_tea#n#1
cat#n#5 : cat-o'-nine-tails#n#1 cat#n#5
cat#n#6 : Caterpillar#n#2 cat#n#6
cat#n#7 : big_cat#n#1 cat#n#7
cat#n#8 : computerized_tomography#n#1 computed_tomography#n#1 CT#n#2 computerized_axial_tomography#n#1 computed_axial_tomography#n#1 CAT#n#8
```

---

P.S.
I have never written perl before, but have been looking into perl scripts since morning - and can now understand the basic stuff. Just need to know if there is cleaner way to do this using the api docs - couldn't figure out from the api or usergroup archives.

Update:

I think I'll settle with:

```
 wn cat -synsn | sed '1,6d' |sed 's/Sense [[:digit:]]//g' | sed 's/[[:space:]]*=> //' | sed '/^$/d'
```

sed rocks!

Comment: Give some sample input/output and you'll get a better answer faster.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @TLP :D .. added some stuff!

Comment: Your output does not seem to have anything to do with cats though.

Comment: By the by, in most simple cases, `sed a | sed b` can usually be combined into a single `sed` script `sed -e a -e b`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you'll find the following hepful...

http://marimba.d.umn.edu/WordNet-Pairs/

What are the N most similar words to X, according to WordNet?

This data seeks to answer that question, where similarity is based on 
measures from WordNet::Similarity. http://wn-similarity.sourceforge.net

### -------------- verb data

These files were created with WordNet::Similarity version 2.05 using
WordNet 3.0. They show all the pairwise verb-verb similarities found
in WordNet according to the path, wup, lch, lin, res, and jcn measures. 
The path, wup, and lch are path-based, while res, lin, and jcn are based 
on information content.

As of March 15, 2011 pairwise measures for all verbs using the six
measures above are availble, each in their own .tar file. Each *.tar
file is named as WordNet-verb-verb-MEASURE-pairs.tar, and is approx 
2.0 - 2.4 GB compressed. In each of these .tar files you will find 
25,047 files, one for each verb sense. Each file consists of 25,048 lines, 
where each line (except the first) contains a WordNet verb sense and the 
similarity to the sense featured in that particular file. Doing
the math here, you find that each .tar file contains about 625,000,000
pairwise similarity values. Note that these are symmetric (sim (A,B) 
= sim (B,A)) so you have a bit more than 300 million unique values.

### -------------- noun data

As of August 19, 2011 pairwise measures for all nouns using the path 
measure are available. This file is named WordNet-noun-noun-path-pairs.tar.
It is approximately 120 GB compressed. In this file you will find 
146,312 files, one for each noun sense. Each file consists of 
146,313 lines, where each line (except the first) contains a WordNet 
noun sense and the similarity to the sense featured in that particular 
file. Doing the math here, you find that each .tar file contains 
about 21,000,000,000 pairwise similarity values. Note that these 
are symmetric (sim (A,B) = sim (B,A)) so you have around 10 billion
unique values.

We are currently running wup, res, and lesk, but do not have an 
estimated date of availability yet.

Comment: Ok ..are you Prof. Predersen from UMN? I dont really know how to control my excitement - /me big fan :D. And I'll be honored change this as the correct answer! Woot!

Comment: I don't think anyone would bother to impersonate me, so yes, it's me. :) Please don't hesitate to ask further questions via our mailing lists or directly - we are pretty quick to get to those, and I really only found the question here by accident. http://wn-similarity.sourceforge.net for more details.

Comment: I wish I had access to this earlier ... with the deadline approaching fast, wonder if I can finish. (Runs to advisor :P)

Answer (score 0):

Put this is a script, say synonym.sh

```
wn $1 -synsn | sed '1,6d' |sed 's/Sense [[:digit:]]//g' | sed 's/[[:space:]]*=> //' | sed '/^$/d' | sed 's/ //g' | grep -iv $1 | tr '\n' ',' 
wn $1 -synsv | sed '1,6d' |sed 's/Sense [[:digit:]]//g' | sed 's/[[:space:]]*=> //' | sed '/^$/d' | sed 's/ //g' | grep -iv $1 | tr '\n' ',';echo
```

From your perl script

```
system("/path/synonym.sh","kittens");
system("/path/synonym.sh","cats");
```

Comment: I am faced with a similar challenge, but I cannot get this to work.

I created  the synonym.sh file, and entered those two commands in a Perl Script.